# Power Query : link 2 tables with 1 id and add one value

Tags: powerquery

I have two tables in Power Query in Excel

- Tickets [id, entities_id, ..]
- Entities [id, level, description, ...]

Joined by: Tickets.entities_id == Entities.id

I'm looking to add a new column into the table Tickets. I want add the value "level" from Entities table based on the value into entity_id.

Could you help me please.
I added a custom column, but I don't know how to put the formula. THANK YOU
(sorry for my english)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Working within the Tickets query, click Home -> Merge Queries -> then, like in the image below, select Entities as the second table to Merge to and select the Tickets[entities_id] column and Entities[id] column for matching and click OK

[image]

Then, at the top of the new Entities column that appears, click the [image] button to expand the column's embedded tables. Uncheck *id*, *description*, and *Use original column name as prefix* like shown below; and click OK.

[image]

You should see something like this:

[image]